# Class 'App\providers\RepositoryServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In local everything is very good but after copy my code to shared server i get this error

> Class 'App\providers\RepositoryServiceProvider' not found

And i can't do any thing by composer because my server is not allowing this.
what can i do?

Comment: Is the file actually present on your shared server?

Comment: Check the uppercase and lowercase if your local env is Windows. I can see `providers` without upper `P`

Comment: @cbaconnier you are right, i change it to uppercase and my problem is solved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as @cbaconnier said, your path might be wrong, change it to:
App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider

The bad news is that most likely you don't have the package installed.
Maybe try and sort the composer issue on your server, i doubt this will be the only package missing without running a composer install.